# Class Illuminate\Http\Request\MedicineValidation does not exist

Tags: laravel

when i use store function for storing data then the validation is working successfully but when i use the update function then the error comes . How to solve this problem?

```php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Medicine;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Http\Requests;

    use App\Models\Medicine\MedicineList;
    use App\Models\Medicine\MedicineGenericName;
    use App\Models\Medicine\MedicineBrand;
    use App\Models\Medicine\MedicineType;



    use Redirect;
    use Toastr;
    use Exception;
    use Auth;
    use DB;
    use Entrust;
    use Datatables;
    use Crypt;
```

In store function:

```php
    public function store(Requests\MedicineValidation $request)
    {
       //code working successfully 
    }
```

In update function:

```php
    public function update(Requests\MedicineValidation $request, $id)
    {
       //Error comes Class Illuminate\Http\Request\MedicineValidation 
       //does  not exist

    }
```

MedicineValidation class path is"App\Http\Requests\MedicineValidation"

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MedicineValidation extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'medicine_name'    => 'required|string|max:250',
            'medicineType'     => 'required|numeric',
            'generic_name'     => 'required|numeric',
            'brand_name'       => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello,
is it possible to paste the full code of update function ? and also run "php artisan route:list"  and paste the result for us.

Comment: Can you post namespace of your `MedicineValidation` class here? I doubt the namespace is not correctly set up.

Comment: You're certain you didn't leave off the `s` in `Requests\MedicineValidation`? You'd get that error if you accidentally typed `Request\MedicineValidation`.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the class really exists
- Maybe your MedicineValidation class namespace is wrong. It should be `App\Http\Requests`
- run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Yes you are right. Previously i present here wrongly. This class actually exists.

Comment: Edit and add your `MedicineValidation` class to the question

Comment: chang your import to `use App\Http\Requests\MedicineValidation`, and use just `MedicineValidation` instead of `Requests\MedicineValidation` wihtin the controller. Run `composer dump-autoload` also